# Kanbanish visualization and workflow management for multi-project, multi-team department

Tags: project-management, agile, kanban

I'm trying to think of a simple (and agile in nature) way to visualize a large department's work and bottlenecks, with the idea of gradually improving the process once we have the necessary data.

The problem is that we have multiple groups of developers working on multiple projects. Some developers are cross-project and some projects are cross-team. Developers are very set in their ways (we don't want to force C# or Java developers to learn Delphi 6 during pair programming).

Another issue is that a very small QA team is shared between all developers/projects.

I need ideas for how to organize a Kanban (or similar) taskboard so that stories are categorized by project (or team?) but that the WIP limits are still applied across the board.

Also, how would the standup meetings go? Including everyone in a single meeting would take up too much time and result in information overload, but splitting the meeting makes us lose out on a lot of the transparency that agile enforces.

So, any ideas related to taskboards and standup meetings are welcome.
Also, alternatives to Kanban with the same level of prescription as Kanban (in other words not much) are very welcome.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not within the scope of questions appropriate for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to get help on [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se].

Answer (score 6):

[Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com) could be a solution in this situation. Eylean board offers data slicing in visual level and in data level. Arrange by rows, columns, categories, assignments. It supports task grouping into categories which can work as different projects and may be placed into different rows of the task board. Any of these options leaves ability to apply WIP limits across the board. The app itself was built to suite kanban so you should find helpful.

[image: Kanban board]
[image: Cumulative workflow diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Corey Ladas over at [Lean Software Engineering](http://leansoftwareengineering.com/) has a few articles on how to design a Kanban board for various workflows. I also highly recommend the [kanbandev mailing list](http://finance.groups.yahoo.com/group/kanbandev/) - the community is pretty mature, but searching through the archives should prove useful.

For standup meetings, keep in mind that Kanban does not prescribe the standard Scrum-style standup (What did you do yesterday, what did you do today, any blockages?). These can still be useful to do with smaller groups, but with a larger team (you never mention how large - 20? 200?) you can just focus on the blockages. What people are currently working on is visible for all on the board, and the next priority (i.e. What will I do next?) should be in some sort of "Ready" queue, which is pulled from according to your different classes of service.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to think of a simple (and agile in nature) way to visualize a large department's work and bottlenecks, with the idea of gradually improving the process once we have the necessary data.

Maybe not the expected answer but this is *exactly* what [value stream mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_stream_mapping) is for:

[image]
<sub>(source: [killen.org](http://killen.org/agileforexecutives/wp-content/uploads/ValueStreamMap.gif))</sub>

And this is where you should start.

Have a look at Mary Poppendieck material on this subject (e.g. [this presentation](http://www.agiles2008.org/common/pdfs/Poppendieck%20-%20Value%20Stream%20Mapping.pdf), [this one](http://www.teamdoty.us/TeamDoty/WebSites/DeepLean/DeepLean-4%20-%20Poppendieck%20-%20Value%20Stream%20Mapping%20-%20color.pdf), or her books).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't read lean development all the way through (loved what I read though). If a Poppendieck has a recommended approach I'll definitely have a look!

Comment: @kevint The sample given above is very simplified but value stream mapping is *the* visualization tool in Lean to identify, demonstrate and decrease waste in the process (optimize the whole,
implement lean across your entire value stream and the complete product). So, map your value stream and start to remove bottlenecks (this is basic Theory Of Constraints applied).

Answer (score 0):

In Agile projects, it's a common practice to visualize and share project status using charts or diagrams on boards. While no single document delivers all of the ammunition agile teams need to get the rhythm, this set of visual materials offers an easy framework to help guide software development teams through the various agile cycles.

A variation of the Kanban, an easy way to represent these cards, with some enhancements to this representation and a synchronized use of the concept, ArabiaGIS introduced the Sync Kanban concept.

The Sync Kanban is composed of a board for each project where the team leader or the responsible developer will try to represent the project status and the features progress with pies.

for complete description: http://www.jaftalks.com/Home/Show/Sync-Kanban-Agile-Project-Management

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is impossible to have a physical or (any other) board that shows projects, teams and development flow **simultaneously**. Moreover, there is no software that provides good team-level visibility, almost all project management tools built on top of Project concept, and little use Team concept.

I've been thinking about this problem for 2 years and came up with a solution that we are going to implement in [TargetProcess](http://www.targetprocess.com), but we are not there yet. The basic idea is to allow to filter and group work flexibly by teams or by projects to provide bird-eye view and zoom in to see details for particular project or particular team. I can't imagine how it can be done on physical kanban board.

Here are [some ideas](http://groups.google.com/group/uxtargetprocess/web/targetprocess-v-3-concept-history-problems-and-solution?hl=en).